# Spring Integration SFTP - Reuse existing task scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a problem when using this line in my context.xml

```
<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>
```

It throws this error

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor com.test.service.MyServices.taskExecutor; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: myOwnScheduler,taskScheduler
```

It seems like the channel create its own task scheduler and it troubles my autowired properties

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
```

So how can I make the channel reuse back my own scheduler, instead of creating a new one ? Or is there any suggestion to fix this ?

I'm using Spring Integration v4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bean (with the following names: myOwnScheduler, taskScheduler) of type TaskExecutor so spring can't decide which one to use. So he throws this exception. You need to use a qualifier like this:

```
@Qualifier("myOwnScheduler")
@Autowired(required = false)
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
```

Comment: yup.. i tried to use this way but I got this class not found exception `org.springframework.util.IdGenerator`. I think it is because of the old project, it is using spring-context 3.2.8.. Is there any other way without changing the java class and only change the context.xml?

Comment: When you are using the qualifier you are going little further in your application startup. And you encounter another error. This error occurs because you are using incompatible spring-framework version. Spring integration 4.0.x requires spring framework 4.0.3 (min). And you can see that [IdGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/IdGenerator.html) was introduced in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing `TaskScheduler` and `TaskExecutor`. The framework provides a default scheduler (bean name `taskScheduler`), but not an executor.

[Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler).